# How could I fill in my circle with a solid color using the distance formula?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in c++ and have coded a for loop to show a hollow circle when I run the code, however, I was wondering how I could achieve a filled-in circle using the distance formula (d = sqrt((ax-bx)^2 + (ay-by)^2). Here's what I have so far! Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

```
int MAX = 728;
for (float t = 0; t < 2 * 3.14; t += 0.01)
    SetPixel(MAX / 4 + MAX / 6 * sin(t), MAX / 4 + MAX / 6 * cos(t), 255, 255, 0);
```

Comment: What you want is a flood fill algorithm. The distance formula won't help you with that.

Comment: @Frecklefoot you can use the distance formula easily if you iterate over the bounding box of the circle.

Comment: Well, we have to calculate the pixel area inside the circle and setPixel over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow(); // Get a console handle
    HDC consoleDC = GetDC(consoleWindow);    // Get a handle to device context

    int max = 628;
    float i = 0;
    float t;
    float doublePi = 6.29;

    for (i = 0.0; i < max; i += 2.0) {
        for (t = 0.0; t < doublePi; t += 0.01) {
            SetPixel(consoleDC, max / 4 + (max - i) / 6 * sin(t), max / 4 + (max - i) / 6 * cos(t), RGB(255, 255, 0));
        }
    }

    ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, consoleDC);
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Working almost well. Draw and fill in! A little slow...

Comment: It works but I wouldn't want it to open a separate window

Comment: Nevermind I got it working for what I was doing! Thanks to everyone for contributing I really appreciate it tremendously!

Comment: @Ian Copenhaver , I appreciate your question tremendously too because because when trying to answer I learned what I didn't know!

Comment: @Ian Copenhaver , the window thing is the instance of the open window. Its the way to manipulate its pixels

Answer (score 1):

Pffff... do not use sin and cos! instead use the sqrt(1-x^2) approach. You can view the formula rendering a circle in google for example: [https://www.google.com/search?q=sqrt(1-x^2)](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqrt(1-x%5E2))

I edit this answer because it seems that is not clear:

```
float radius = 50.0f;
for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; ++x) {
    int d = round(sqrt(1.0f - (x * x / radius / radius)) * radius); 
    for (int y = -d; y <= d; ++y) {
        SetPixel(x, y, 255, 255, 0);
    }
}
```

Note: each graphic library is different, so I assumed that you used rightfully the "SetPixel" function.

Now, for most people say the sqrt(1-x^2) approach should be enough, but it seem that some downvoters does not think the same XD.

Comment: This be a comment, not an answer. You can salvage this by filling it out so that it doesn't rely so much on a link to a google search.

Comment: The google search is for view the graphic. Google has a graphic calculator. Did you opened that link?

Comment: Unfortunately that makes your answer even less an answer. I thought you were at least trying to be helpful by pointing the asker at an algorithm to implement.

Comment: Hope you are happy: the efficient way to draw a circle XD.

Comment: Much better. Have you profiled this against the [Bresenham Circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm#Variant_with_integer-based_arithmetic)? May be some performance gains from sticking in integer math.

Comment: On second thought, Bresenham just gets the circle, it doesn't fill.

Comment: sqrt can be tabulated, round can be embeded, breseham can be used to access the table, pixel can be rendered by line scans... this is the base algorithm only, optimizations can be done... of course. The idea is: do not use sin or cos, even drawing the outside.

Comment: That I'm not arguing with sin and cos are murderous.

Answer (score 1):

Inefficient as can be, and probably the last way you really want to draw a circle ... but ...

Over the entire square encompassing your circle, calculate each pixel's distance from the center and set if under or equal the radius.

```
// Draw a circle centered at (Xcenter,Ycenter) with given radius using distance formula

void drawCircle(HDC dc, int XCenter, int YCenter, int radius, COLORREF c) {
    double fRad = radius * 1.0; // Just a shortcut to avoid thrashing data types

    for (int x = XCenter - radius; x<XCenter + radius; x++) {
        for (int y = YCenter - radius; y<YCenter + radius; y++) {
            double d = sqrt(((x - XCenter) * (x - XCenter)) + ((y - YCenter) * (y - YCenter)) );
            if (d <= fRad) SetPixel(dc, x, y, c);
        }
    }
}
```

**Caveat:** No more caveat, used a C++ environment and tested it this time. :-)

Call thusly:

```
int main()
{
    HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC consoleDC = GetDC(consoleWindow);

    drawCircle(consoleDC, 50, 50, 20, RGB(255, 0, 255));

    ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, consoleDC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but when I run your code I just get two squares. I uploaded a screenshot in my post

Comment: There could easily be a bug in my code example -- additionally, there's no error checking on the parameters at all.  My code assumes you've given a center point and radius that won't result in any negative values. I didn't add the standard caveat ... will do so. :-)

Comment: Oh, and my employer's network rules don't allow me to download images.

Comment: There WAS a bug in my code ... dummy me was using ^ as a power operator -- C doesn't have one of those. The two squares made for an interesting mystery. :-)

It's fixed now.

Comment: You don't need `sqrt`, that would make it a touch more efficient. Just square the distance calculation, and also square the radius that you're comparing against.

Comment: Efficiency was not a goal of this solution, as noted in the intro. :-)

Comment: I read the efficiency comment as a before-the-fact apology, not as a design goal. The overall approach is sound, and squaring the formula is a simple but effective way to make it faster without complicating it. I've used it myself many times.

Comment: Nah, that was more a statement of fact; but i can see how you'd read it that way.  :-) 

The question presented the design goal: use the distance formula to draw the circle, so I used the formula as given and didn't try to enhance it.  [ MOF, that's where my ^-as-exponent-operator bug crept in too, blindly following the stated goal. :-) ] 

You're absolutely correct, squaring the desired difference rather than calculating square roots is way more efficient.